Use DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT with tkinter
I am Using tkinter for a small application. Using
from ctypes import windll
windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2)

I wanted to adjust the application on my dual monitor setup (with two different kind of montiors (Laptop and Display)). But it doesn't work 100%. The application opens on my Laptop screen very sharp and just the size I want it to be. Moving it to the other monitor it becomes very large (probably trying to keep the same scale on the large display) and looks unnatural.
Then I stumbeld over this webiste https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/dpi-awareness-context
It describes a newer Verison of SetProcessDpiAwareness, SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext, which has a V2 of the Monitor resacling.
But it doesnt seem to work in tkinter, even though I have Windows 11 pro.
